# Buttons in the action bar vs on screen

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar, user-experience

I have a question that is more about the user experience than a technical issue. As such, it may not belong here (let me know if it doesn't) but it's something that's bothering me.

I'm building an application to help with learning English which has a quiz section with multiple choice questions. Most of the applications like that (including my old applications developed for Android 2.x) have a layout of the screen that goes like:

- Answer 1
- Answer 2
- Answer 3
- Button "Check"
- Button "Skip"

The user selects an answer and clicks the button to check it and go to the next question. If they don't want to answer the question, they press Skip. That layout is quite intuitive and easy to grasp.

Now, I would like to use the action bar for all the actions the user may take. My problem is that while having Next action is ok (with the icon of arrow pointing right), adding another action of Skip makes the action bar unclear. Is just my inability to come up with the right icon for skipping? Or is it a problem with the icons in the action bar not necessarily being easy to understand and use?

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActionBar is not the place for such actions.
UI-wise, the hierarchy of of an app such as your should be (imo):

- ActionBar with general actions (for example settings , share question...)
- Question
- Answers
- Check and Skip

From top to bottom

Comment: I kind of agree with that. But then I looked at the Gmail app and they used icons in the action bar for individual actions that you can perform on an email.
Another thing is, after I put all the actions into the action bar, my app started to look more slick and modern...

Comment: UI/User experience-wise I don't think that it will work for an app such as yours. You can give it to someone to play with to see how he reacts...
regarding gmail, those items in the actionbar make sense(they do not depend on the content of the email below, but are general and affect what happens to the mail).
Think that your user is looking at your activity from top to bottom. The flow is: read question -> choose answer -> skip/check. in makes no sense for him to move back up to the action bar

Comment: Thanks for the effort in trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer to put buttons belonging to the content (such as the question) WITH the content. Then I find buttons that interact with the app as a whole to belong to the action bar. It can also be used if it interacts with multiple content items on single screen (more common on tablets

For example putting a login button in a login screen in the action bar would be kinda awkward..

Im no UI expert by any means though

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I think too but it makes my app inconsistent. I guess it strongly depends on the actual actions.
I finally put all the actions/buttons into the action bar and changed their icons so that they are more clear. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Action Bar would be better for your situation.. try drawing your idea about the UI in a piece of paper, that really helps a lot about UI decisions